# SharePoint 2010 Central Administration link not working

Tags: 2010, central-administration

I have problem on a SharePoint 2010 Server installation where the Central Admin icon/link (the one in start menu) isn't working.

It opens a browser with a URL to the root address of the server, then it starts looping 302-requests back to itself '/' finally ending in a page not found.
To access central admin I have to either type server:port/default.aspx or browse from iis which also goes to the root address but then it redirects correctly to default.aspx

I have confirmed that [CentralAdministrationUrl] in Registry contains the correct url (server:port).

any thoughts?

Comment: I think your IIS entry for CA is being modified by some reason. The default page is redirecting to wrong url or page

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the target of your Central Admin start menu shortcut is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\psconfigui.exe" -cmd showcentraladmin
```

Also, when you click the link in your start menu the URL ought to include the port number.

Accessing CA via server:port/default.aspx (as you mention above) is correct.

Comment: Yes the target of the shortcut is correct. But the shortcut doesnt work as I stated above. The url loops at servername:portnumber/ and ending in a: "This page can't be displayed"... I either have to manually type the address or browse from iis.